# Glide 4.13.0 : thumbnail(float) is deprecated

Tags: java, android, thumbnails, deprecated, android-glide

Just updated Glide to Version **4.13.0** and getting this deprecation warning.

On checking the release page, I found this:[image]

So, what should be the appropriate equivalent to this part of code?

```
GlideApp.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
            .load(sr)
            .thumbnail(0.2f)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.background_splash)
            .into(holder.album);
```

**What I tried:**
[image]

I think the syntax should be something like this but confused on what to pass to the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `RequestBuilder` you can configure the request for thumbnail with a multiplier. below is an example

```
 RequestBuilder<Drawable> requestBuilder= GlideApp.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
            .asDrawable().sizeMultiplier(0.1f);
 GlideApp.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
            .load(sr)
            .thumbnail(requestBuilder)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.background_splash)
            .into(holder.album);
```

its should work . just play around with it to explore more options .

Answer (score 2):

You can use sizeMultiplier instead of thumbnail as below;

> Useful for loading thumbnails or trying to avoid loading huge
> resources (particularly Bitmaps on devices with overly dense screens.

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(products[position].imageSource)
        .sizeMultiplier(0.6f)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(holder.rowImage)
```